# Agregar valores que no se repitan al analizar el resultado de un fetch

Tags: javascript, ajax, push

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de *pushear* los valores del segundo `then` al array global `frasesChuck` sin que se repitan los valores, ya que cada vez que llama a la función llamar *API* solo devuelve un resultado *random*.

```js
var frasesChuck = [];

function llamarAPI() {
    let url = "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random";

    fetch(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                throw 'Hubo un error al llamar la API'
            }
        })
        .then(function (json) {
            // console.log(json.value);
            let frases = json.value;
            console.log(frases);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

```html
<body onload="llamarAPI()">
```

Comment: Puedes hacer una comprobación para saber si ya existe en el `array` `if(frasesChuck.indexOf(frases) == -1)`y si no existe pushearlo `frasesChuck.push(frases);`

Answer (score 0):

A partir de ECMAScript 2016 puedes usar [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes) para comprobar si un elemento existe en un array antes de insertarlo.

Por ejemplo:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("callAPI").onclick = llamarAPI;

  var frasesChuck = [];

  function llamarAPI() {
    let url = "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random";

    fetch(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw 'Hubo un error al llamar la API'
        }
      })
      .then(function(json) {
        // console.log(json.value);
        let frases = json.value;
        if (!frasesChuck.includes(frases)) {
          frasesChuck.push(frases);
        }

        console.log(frasesChuck);



      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);

      });


  }
});
```

```html
<button id="callAPI">Llamar API</button>
```

---

En versiones anteriores a ECMASCript 2016 puedes usar [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf). Cuando este valor no sea mayor que `-1` significa que el elemento no existe.

En ambos códigos he cambiando el load del `body` por un botón, para que se pueda probar el código en el snippet.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("callAPI").onclick = llamarAPI;

  var frasesChuck = [];

  function llamarAPI() {
    let url = "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random";

    fetch(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw 'Hubo un error al llamar la API'
        }
      })
      .then(function(json) {
        // console.log(json.value);
        let frases = json.value;

        if (!frasesChuck.indexOf(frases) > -1) {
          frasesChuck.push(frases);
        }

        console.log(frasesChuck);



      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);

      });


  }
});
```

```html
<button id="callAPI">Llamar API</button>
```